# Source Not Avaliable when switching to other thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, winapi, windows-runtime

I am writing on C++ with winapi, winrt, and wil in Visual Studio 2022.

I am using Winapi multithreading tools, `::CreateThread` particularly.

When I debug or build my program, everything is fine.

When I was debugging programs and switching to other threads, created by me, I was getting an error:

> ntdll.pdb not loaded

I saw an option to locate manually, which I clicked, but now it says:

> Source Not Avaliable
> Source information is missing from the debug information for this module

Before and after location, when switching to other thread I was also having this message:

> The application is in break mode
> Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).

The only option left on screen is `View Dissasembly`, which shows me some dissasembly code instead of source code.

Comment: ***I was getting ntdll.pdb not loaded*** Do you really need to debug inside Microsoft's system dlls? If you do you can enable the symbol server to download the pdbs for system files. I usually don't do that because it makes my application startup take longer because it searches for missing pdbs for files that are not Microsoft (like my GPU drivers). [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022]

Comment: You probably just want to switch the call stack to your code and not debug inside the system dlls.

Comment: And regardless the source isn't going to be available (even when the kernel checked builds were available that still didn't provide the kernel source).

Comment: The description is consistent with what is to be expected. You seem to expect something else to happen but don't explain what that is. Microsoft doesn't supply the source code for its operating system implementation (unless you formally request it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in threads, which processed some system dll first, and then my code.
I was switching to them too early

Comment: I'm glad you have got your solution and thank for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.